# How to integrate CLU (conversational language understanding) with bot framework SDK for NodeJs

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have a basic echo bot (**nodejs**) from *Azure Bot Framework SDK*. I saw there is an npm package called **`botbuilder-ai`** which includes many functions. `LUISRecognizer` is one of them. Using that function, we can configure Azure LUIS in our nodejs bot application.

As per the Azure document, `LUIS` is going to retire and `CLU` (*Conversational Language Understanding*) is the replacement of LUIS.

**My question is whether there is any package or function to integrate CLU into the application.**

Answer (score 0):

Generally, everything you need for CLU integration in your Bot Project is a prediction URL from the Language Studio Project (look at this [article](https://ruby.mobidev.biz/posts/azure-cognitive-services-for-your-chatbot/) for details). Just call it using users' inputs as parameters. In addition, you can write a custom client class to transform the output from CLU and get only valuable information from it (you can filter by confidence score, number of top answers, etc.). Such an approach will be even more flexible than using the additional package.